# Multi nested Datagridview contol (Free Control)

Tags: c#, winforms

Please help me to find out a free C# WinForm `DataGridView`-Control which support multilevel nested sub(child) grids ,which support editable columns in child and that child grid also. not just Child parent relation grid,at least four to five level nested grid.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/ especially its `TreeListView` or even just `ObjectListView` which shoult be capable of handling your hierarchical type of requirement.